# How to send a variable through Javascript formData API

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get AJAX file (picture) upload working, but I'm having some problems sending variables through the formData API:

This is the formData code:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('SelectedFile', _file.files[0]);
data.append('name', event_title);
```

As you can see on line 3 I am trying to send a variable to the server at the same time. event_title is defined as

```
var event_title = document.getElementById("new_event_title").value;
```

And that is called before the formData code.

I can send normal text through to the server just fine, for example

```
date.append("name", "enter-name");
```

However when I change this to a variable it stops working.

I've checked MDN and HTML5rocks to no avail, so if anyone could help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? If static text works fine, and variables don't, then it's almost certainly a problem with the variable.

Comment: Thanks Drahcir, I checked the console and the only error I found was:

    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: I've no idea then, it must be something else on your page that causes the problem. Maybe you could post a cut down version of your code on JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

This code demonstrates how it's possible to send a file and a variable string parameter at the same time:

```js
document.getElementById("submitBtn").onclick = function(){
    var event_title = document.getElementById("new_event_title").value;
    var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('SelectedFile', file);
    data.append('name', event_title);
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://example.com/', true);
    xhr.send(data);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="new_event_title" value="My Event Title">
<input type="file" id="file">
<br>
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Send">
```

Click above to run the code and look in the network tab of the browser console, you'll see the data is sent. I suspect your problem is related to other code on your page.